# How to resolve qmake catkin_make conflict

Tags: makefile, cmake, qt-creator, qmake, catkin

While I was trying to compile qt-quick application that embedded catkin project, I added a custom build step as below image shows.

[image]

The problem is that it has compile error as follow:

make: (no rule to make target 'cmake_check_build_system')

I think the Makefile automatically generated is overwritten repeatedly and results compilation error. How should I do? or What am I misunderstanding?

JB

Answer (score 0):

I disabled qmake (as I did to Make(see the image above) and build the project using catkin_make only. Now the problem is basically gone.